# Codeigniter project is not running other AMP server except XAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, wamp, easyphp

My codeIgniter project is running well in Xamp 1.7.3 but not work in any other local server (e.g. Easy PHP, WAMP etc).

My httaccess file

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml index.htm home.htm default.htm index.fcgi default.html

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pwame/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: how is it not working.

Comment: what is the error if you turn on showing of the php errors?

Answer (score 1):

Your .HTACCESS will not work with WAMP server. Change your base url in config.php with following

```
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/yourproject/index.php/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a weird htaccess but whatever.

Have you activated the Apache rewrite_module, by default I dont think it is activated.

Left click the wamp manager icon in the system tray -> Apache -> Apache Modules -> rewrite_module

Find it in the menu list and if it is not ticked, click it and wait 10seconds for Apache to be restarted and then you should be good to go.